# Unable to select rows programatically in drawCallback() of DataTables

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatable

I am using the latest datatables with select extension. I am trying to select multiple rows programatically after the table is rendered. I am trying to achieve this in the drawCallback() as below:

```
var table = $('#example').DataTable({
    "select": {
      "style": 'multi'
    },
    "columns": [
      { "data": "name" },
      { "data": "position" },
      { "data": "office" },
      { "data": "age" },
      { "data": "start_date" },
      { "data": "salary" }
    ],
    "rowId": "name",
    "drawCallback": function( settings ) {
      var api = new $.fn.dataTable.Api( settings );
      api.rows(["[id='Bradley Greer']", "[id='Ashton Cox']"]).select();
    }
 });
```

But, I am getting an `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of undefined` error.

Here is the link for live version - http://live.datatables.net/yemiqafu/2/

**P.S:** I have used `[id='Bradley Greer']` as selector since there is a space in the id. I had to do this for live demo and this is not the reason for the error that is thrown.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **SOLUTION**

Option [`drawCallback`](http://datatables.net/reference/option/drawCallback) is not a correct place to perform row selection.

Ideally, you should use [`initComplete`](http://datatables.net/reference/option/initComplete) option instead, but there was an [issue](https://github.com/DataTables/DataTables/issues/697) with Select extension that was [fixed 10/7/15](https://github.com/DataTables/Select/commit/6cc6c6ef944a44119a96b7aa14e85fe3ad5cf16f) which prevented Select to work in `initComplete`. Until then you can use the workaround below for HTML sourced data or use [nightly build](http://datatables.net/download/nightly) of DataTables and Select extension.

For table with data from HTML source you can select your rows after DataTables initialization.

```js
var table = $('#example').DataTable({
    "select": {
      "style": 'multi'
    },
    "columns": [
      { "data": "name" },
      { "data": "position" },
      { "data": "office" },
      { "data": "age" },
      { "data": "start_date" },
      { "data": "salary" }
    ],
    "rowId": "name"       
});

table.rows(["[id='Bradley Greer']", "[id='Ashton Cox']"]).select();
```

> **DEMO**

See [this example](http://live.datatables.net/yemiqafu/4) for code and demonstration of a workaround for table with HTML sourced data.

See [this example](http://live.datatables.net/yemiqafu/7) for code and demonstration of using nightly JS/CSS builds for table with Ajax sourced data. This example could be used for HTML sourced data as well.

Comment: Forgot to mention that I want to achieve this when using ajax data source. That is why I tried drawCallback(). Is there any way to select rows when loading data using ajax?

Comment: @Vivek, use nightly build of DataTables/Select extension. See [this example](http://live.datatables.net/yemiqafu/7) for Ajax sourced data.